# skeleton grid system: make container 100%

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate, grid-system

is it possible to make the the root div (container) 100% of the document?
here's my code:

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="topbar" class="sixteen columns" style="background-color:green;">topbar topbar topbar topbar topbar topbar </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: `div` always is 100% (if not overrided).

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want the final product to look like? Or what it looks like now?

Comment: He's using a responsive platform called Skeleton.  He's trying to override the container class that is provided with Skeleton to have a a full browser width container instead of one that is limited to 1140px.  He needs to define his own styles to do this rather than overriding what already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to create your own container class.  I don't know what the css for the skeleton responsive platform looks like off the top of my head.  I use one called Columnal, I know it is similar, so it should be something like this...

```
.full-width-container {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The normal css should be something like `.container { max-width: 1140px; width: 100%; clear: both; margin: 0 auto; }`

Answer (score 18):

I know this question was asked ages ago but Skeleton has utility classes for this.

Basically add the `.u-full-width` and `.u-max-full-width` classes to any `<div>` with class `.container`.

Just make sure it's on the `<div>` element with class `.container`, as it doesn't seem to be meant for the `<div>` elements with `.row` or `.column` classes.

Comment: My version of Skeleton seems to be too old to have `.u-full-width`. Fortunately, it looks like the CSS for it is quite simple: `.u-full-width { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }`